# How to save a form's layout at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serialization

I have a project in which I create a blank form and add controls to it from a XML template at runtime. This works well, but it takes a bit of time to do it. I want to know if it is possible to save the layout of the form to a .NET format after it has been defined at runtime so I don't have to keep parsing the xml to create the form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot serialize `windows.forms.control` but the links below should help you

[How to serialize a windows form and other child controls in c# and save them into table](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9de0d09d-537a-49a0-a260-877f47b42c89)

[How to Clone/Serialize/Copy & Paste a Windows Forms Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12976/How-to-Clone-Serialize-Copy-Paste-a-Windows-Forms)

By the way you should have a look at WPF for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Form.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) is a list of [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). Each of these controls contains a Width, Height and Location property that you can use in your serialization back to your XML document.

Basically the point i'm trying to make is that you could just serialize the Form.Controls